# log4j: Issue with MDC configuration

Tags: java, struts2, log4j, mdc

I am trying to add the username for each log. I found that MDC is the appropriate solution to do that and I followed [that tutorial](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/11/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code/).

Here is a log snippet, for testing purpose; I print the word "TEST" instead of the username :

```
2013-09-30 11:24:03,087 INFO  company.filter.AuthenticationFilter - TEST - AuthenticationFilter is called
2013-09-30 11:24:03,089 INFO  company.filter.AuthenticationFilter - TEST - userName is removed
2013-09-30 11:24:03,089 INFO  company.filter.AuthenticationFilter - TEST - AuthenticationFilter is called
2013-09-30 11:24:03,089 INFO  company.filter.AuthenticationFilter - TEST - userName is removed
2013-09-30 11:24:03,093 INFO  company.interceptors.AuthentificationInterceptor -  - Interceptor, actionName : Company_getTab redirect to Login_timeOut : false
2013-09-30 11:24:03,094 INFO  company.interceptors.AuthentificationInterceptor -  - Interceptor, actionName : Company_getTop redirect to Login_timeOut : false
2013-09-30 11:24:03,095 INFO  company.interceptors.AuthentificationInterceptor -  - Interceptor, actionName : Company_getBottom redirect to Login_timeOut : false
2013-09-30 11:24:03,124 INFO  company.actions.CompanyAction -  - sample log
```

As you can see, it seems to work only in `AuthenticationFilter`, but not in the Struts2 interceptors or actions.  I implemented `AuthenticationFilter` this way:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
  private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationFilter.class);

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    try {
        MDC.put("userName", "TEST");
        logger.info("AuthenticationFilter is called");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } finally {
        logger.info("userName is removed.");
        MDC.remove("userName");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {}

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}
}
```

I added this to the file `web.xml`:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>company.filter.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

And this this the pattern that I use in `log4j.xml`

```
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %c - %X{userName} - %m%n"/>
</layout>
```

I guess that there is something that I don’t understand about MDC. I thought that MDC would be called for each request so it can set the map which is `ThreadLocal` and each request has it's own thread (I might not understand `ThreadLocal` properly as well.).

What should I look for/modify so I can use MDC in my configuration?

EDIT:

I've added a log so I can see when the data from the map is removed. Their is nothing in the map before the first action/interceptor log. I expected to see something like this:

- AuthenticationFilter - TEST -
- Interceptor log
- AuthenticationFilter userName removed

Comment: What you are doing is seems right, `MDC` works based on `ThreadLocal`, so value set in `MDC` in one thread would be not be visible to other threads. Can you check `MDC` references in your codebase if anywhere `MDC.clear` is being called? Ideally if you set in `Filter` it should be visible to `Action` classes as they are called in same thread unless removed or cleared..

Comment: `MDC.clear`is never called within the code base. I added a log so I can see when the function `MDC.remove` is called. The map is empty before each action log. I've updated my question with this new element.

Comment: Have you checked your <root> tag inside log4j.xml. The <priority > tag should be at lower level to pick the appenders inside you have added your MDC place holders.

Comment: I forgot to write an update... for some reason, it started to work on its own. I guess some configuration files were not properly deployed or something similar did cause the issue...